# Convert np.array binary in an single binary number

Tags: python, numpy

I need to convert the example array:

```
array([0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1])
```

in :

```
[01000001]
```

but when i use:

```
int("".join(map(str, array)))
```

return:

```
[1000001]
```

How can i solve it ?

Comment: does the ouput have to be integer or it can be string ? Because if you want an integer How can an Integer be starting with 0.

Answer (score 0):

You should specify the base in which the number is provided.
By default it is `10` but in your case it's `2`.

So:

```
int("".join(map(str, array)), 2)
```

Should do the trick

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have an integer staring with 0, in case string is good enough you an just remove **int** from your code like

```
"".join(map(str, array))
```